# Resize Jive Addon Tile Vertically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jive

I'm running an angular application inside a Jive tile and am looking for a way to resize the tile container when the view switches state. Has anyone run into something like this?

The tile is deployed to a Jive Cloud instance through a Jive add-on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jive has a JS function that will do that if you call it from within your tile.

```
gadgets.window.adjustHeight();
```

You'll probably need to bind this function to an event or some sorts.